# Using VSCode Python extension with Jupyter and RemoteFS?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I use the RemoteFS extension in VSCode to connect to my remote SSH server. When I open a `.py` file on the remote server in VSCode, and then add `#%%` comment to the `.py` file, I don't get the option to run a Jupyter cell like I would locally.

Has anybody gotten VSCode's Python extension working with it's built-in Jupyter support and the RemoteFS extension?

Comment: Hey user1566200, thanks for reporting this. I'm a developer on that feature. We've not investigated the data science Jupyter cells with RemoteFS before now. Seems like something is off here. I've created an issue (link below) to track this and I'll be looking into it shortly. I'll update here with an answer when we get more info or a resolution.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3995

Comment: @IanHuff - thank you. If there is anything I can provide, please let me know. I've switched to the `SFTP` VSCode extension (by the same author as `RemoteFS`) and that works fine. Presumably because all the `SFTP` extension does is mirror local files to the remote; not sure what `RemoteFS` does.

Answer (score 1):

We had an overly restrictive file check for when we allowed our "Run Cell" commands to show up and it was limiting it to local files only. I've fixed that issue in the following PR here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/pull/4191

I verified that I was seeing the cell commands using Remote FS after that. Sadly this just missed the cutoff for our recent January release, so it won't show up in the extension until later in February. If you want to check out the fix you can access our daily development build here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#development-build

That build has the fix already, but it's not the full public release.